# Large memory usage of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray()

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a fairly large sparse matrix `A` as a [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). It has the following properties:

```
A.shape: (77169, 77169)
A.nnz: 284811011
A.dtype: dtype('float16')
```

Now I have to convert it to a dense array using `.toarray()`. My estimate for the memory usage would be

```
77169**2 * (16./8.) / 1024.**3 = 11.09... GB
```

which would be fine as my machine has ~48GB of memory. In fact, if I create `a=np.ones((77169, 77169), dtype=np.float16)` that works fine and indeed `a.nbytes/1024.**3 = 11.09...`. However, when I run `A.toarray()` on the sparse matrix it packs all of memory and starts to use the swap at some point (it doesn't raise a `MemoryError`). Whats going wrong here? Shouldn't it easily fit into my memory?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  Check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot: SciPy version is 0.15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `csr` `toarray()` does

```
self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
```

you could go on to trace `coo.toarray`, but I suspect it ends up using compiled code.  But I suspect it ends up do the equivalent of:

```
In [715]: M=sparse.random(10,10,.2,format='csr')
In [717]: M=M.astype(np.float16)
In [718]: A = np.zeros(M.shape, M.dtype)
In [719]: Mo=M.tocoo()
In [720]: A[Mo.row, Mo.col] = Mo.data
```

Curiously though if I do

```
In [728]: Mo.toarray()
     ...
    257         coo_todense(M, N, self.nnz, self.row, self.col, self.data,
--> 258                     B.ravel('A'), fortran)
    259         return B
...
ValueError: Output dtype not compatible with inputs.
```

It's having trouble with the `float16`.   `Mo.astype(float).toarray()` works fine.  I get this error even if use `toarray(out=out)` with a float16 out, which makes me suspect `coo_todense` has been compiled with just a couple dtype alternatives.  Maybe I'll dig into that later.

```
In [741]: scipy.__version__
Out[741]: '0.18.1'
```

---

A comment in Warren's bug report

> but the xxx_todense functions are actually A += X,

suggests that the copy from `Mo.data` to `A[]` is more complicated that what indicated.  `toarray` sums duplicates, as it would with `Mo.tocsr()` or `Mo.sum_duplicates()`.

Comment: FYI: I created an issue at the scipy github repository for the error: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7408

Comment: The comment that `float16` is not supported, raises the question of what other operations work or don't with this dtype. `M*M` works, but produces a `float32`.  Evidently it converts the data dtype before passing the arrays to compiled code.

Comment: OK, that leaves me with two workarounds: (1) Use csr_matrix with float32, convert to dense and then convert to float16 or (2) use a float16 csr_matrix and convert to dense manually as you suggested above. They both seem to work but the former appears to be the saver option as stated in @WarrenWeckesser s issue "I think float16 is not a supported sparse matrix type". Who knows what else might be going wrong there....